# Use Azure Custom Vision on images within documents

Tags: c#, .net, azure

As per the title, I'm trying to use Azure custom vision on office documents, such as word and powerpoint, using c#.

I can use custom vision to detect objects with pictures in jpg/png format but if the image is stored in documents the program fails.

Do I need to extract the images from the files first before before calling the prediction api?